# Scroll and zoom to specific CGRect of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have a `UIScrollView` and a `UIImageView` inside. The `UIScrollView` size is `350x350` and the image inside the `UIImageView` is `350x350`.

The `UIScrollView` has a `zoomScale` of **4**.

I want to show only the specific point of the image rect:

`CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)`

For better understanding, only the white rect inside the images:

**x:100, y:100, width:100, height:100**

[image]

**x:150, y:150, width:100, height:100**

[image]

What i've done so far could not do the trick:

```
    self.image.image = UIImage(named: "horse_marked_100x100")
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 10
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1
    self.imageScroller.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imageScroller.delegate = self
    self.imageScroller.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.imageScroller.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100), animated: false)
    self.imageScroller.zoomScale = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```swift
    scrollView.zoom(to: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100), animated: true)
```

You should only take care to have the desired size covered by the `maximumZoomScale` of the scroll view. For instance, in this example, you won't be able to zoom in a rect smaller than `35 x 35`, because you have a `maximumZoomScale` of 10. In your example you don't have any problems with this.

Note: the `CGRect` should be in the coordinate space of the view returned by `viewForZooming(in:)`. This is a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method which must be implemented in order to enable zooming. Here, you have to simply return the `UIImageView` inside the scroll view.

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify what you tried out so far and why it does not work: `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(_:, animated:)` will scroll in a position where the passed `CGRect` is visible, but without zooming the scroll view. In this example, that `CGRect` is already completely visible in the scroll view, thus it doesn't have to scroll anywhere else, so you don't see any visible effect.

Comment: What do you mean by 'covered by the zoomScale'?

Comment: I mean that if you would like to scroll to something like `CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width 20, height: 20)` will not be covered by the zoomScale, because the smallest rectangle that can be obtain with this scale of 4 from an image of 350x350 would be a rectangle of 87,5 x 87,5. Apple's documentation states that you don't have to care about this aspect at all, but I'd recommend to do so. In any case, in your example everything should work just fine.

Comment: Oh, nevermind the fuss about the zoomScale... I was referring to `maximumZoomScale`, which is 10 in your example, which is enough. The `zoomScale` will be changed anyway by the scroll view after you call `scrollView.zoom(to: animated:)`, but you should not care about that. I'll update my answer in a few minutes as well.

Comment: Ok it's working, but I want to fully understand... I divide the size of the image (350x350) by the zoomScale and it gives me the correct location that I want. But how does he know the width / height of the location that I want?

Comment: No, the zoomScale will be changed automatically by the scrollView. But, if you want to zoom to anything smaller than 35 x 35 (which is 350 x 350 divided by maximum zoom scale of 10), then it could be a problem. You don't have it here as you work with 100 x 100. But if you indeed want to zoom for something smaller than 35 x 35, then you need to increase the maximum zoom scale accordingly. What I was talking about the zoom scale alone does not apply because I was confusing it with maximum zoom scale.

Comment: Do I have to consider the contentView frame size? (width and height)